# How to track multiple devices using pubnub?

Tags: mapbox, pubnub

I am using pubnub's eon-map framework for real time data/marker update,
in my case there is multiple teams and each team contain multiple members and each member publish their data on unique channel, **Ex: `xyz-member.id`**

 I wanna track a selected member as well as track all feature.

I have seen [Realtime Flight Tracking Map](https://www.pubnub.com/developers/eon/map/flight/) but in that example they publish all the data from one node rather than multiple nodes.

**Map Config:**

```
let pn = new PubNub({
  publishKey: 'key', 
  subscribeKey: 'key'  
});

let map = eon.map({
  pubnub: pn,
  id: 'tracking-map',
  mbToken: 'token',
  mbId: 'id',
  //channels array equal to members.length
  channels: ['xyz-member.id', 'xyz-member.id', 'xyz-member.id'], 
  message: (data, token, ch) => {
    map.setView(data[0].latlng, 15);
  }
});
```

**Publish Ex:**

```
pn.publish({
  channel: 'xyz-member.id', //each member create their own channel.
  message:  [
    {"latlng": [latitude, longitude]}
  ]
});
```

[image]

Comment: The simple answer is that you can publish from multiple nodes. Are you finding an issue with doing so?

Comment: Yes, when I am publishing from multiple nodes, I am getting only one marker on map and it is updated whenever any new data come from any channel.

Comment: OK, there is a way for this work as I have done it before. You can expect a nice answer from PubNub soon.

Comment: @CraigConover have you done this before ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can certainly publish from many nodes. Your EON map can subscribe to only 1 channel. You will need to publish to the same channel for every member. The message should contain a unique key for every beacon on the map.

[image]

Member A

```
pubnub.publish({
  channel: 'map',
  message: {
    point_1: {
      latlng: [37.370375, -97.756138]
    }
  }
});
```

Member B

```
pubnub.publish({
  channel: 'map',
  message: {
    point_2: {
      latlng: [23.234, -94.32346]
    }
  }
});
```

EON map subscribe:

```
channels: ['map']
```

A helpful code example for this scenario **Distributed.html** is here: https://github.com/pubnub/eon-map/tree/master/examples

Comment: You are right but I am using map and want to show marker on map rather than chart, see attachment I have added in question

Comment: not enough jquery https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:6385315001942577152

Comment: I edited the answer so it now explains the implementation for a map instead of a chart.

Comment: @Adam: I was checked this but didn't success, it is create only one marker and update this marker whenever data is updated.

Comment: You need to specify more than 1 **point** in the message if you want to have more than 1 marker on the map. You can see in the above answer there is `point_1` and `point_2` in the message objects, which yields 2 markers on the map.